# Refresh listview with Section headers

Tags: android

I am using a listview with section headers as in this example.

http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/

The problem is if I delete or add an item, the sections are all wrong. The sections seem to be set up in the constructor of the Adapter so there seems to be no way of refreshing the sections without creating a new adapter. Is there any way to recreate the section headers correctly without creating a new adapter

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new adapter to update your ListView's contents. Simply store your Adapter in a field and update your list with the following code:

```
mAdapter.setList(yourNewList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To clarify that, your Activity should look like that:

```
private YourAdapter mAdapter;

protected void onCreate(...) {

    ...

    mAdapter = new YourAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    updateData();
}

private void updateData() {
    List<Data> newData = getYourNewData();
    mAdapter.setList(yourNewList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I also have same problem on http://ngo-hung.com/blog/2012/11/18/ios-contact-listview-for-android  may you give me suggetion how can i solved problem like this.